# Does my refrigerator's water line require a shutoff valve behind the refrigerator?

Tags: refrigerator

Is there a code requiring a water shut off valve to be behind a refrigerator with an ice maker/water dispenser?  This pertains to New York State ( Rockland County).

Comment: Have you contacted your local building department?

Answer (score 3):

Yes.  Sort of.  It doesn't require it to be behind the fridge, but it does require one on the supply.

> ## Uniform Plumbing Code
>
> **606.0 Valves**
>
> **606.5 Control Valves.** A control valve shall be installed ahead of each water-supplied appliance and immediately ahead of each slip joint or appliance supply.

Unless your county has amended the code.